# Using 'getrandom' to generate random number in C++

Tags: c++, random

I want to use a random-number-generator in c++ to make a maths quiz with randomly-generated numbers.

My problem is that using `time(0)` is only accurate to a single second. In the IDE that I am using (NetBeans 8.2), a message appeared when hovering over `srand(time(0))` with the message:

[image: Image of the text]

> This is a weak random number generator; it is not useful for security purposes. Alternative: getrandom(void *buf,size_t buflen, unsigned int flags);/dev/urandom;

I could not find anything online about `getrandom`. I was wondering if anyone could shed some light on the syntax of `getrandom`? How to use it?

Comment: Do you want to make a random number generator or use one?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

Comment: Do you really need security strength for your random generator?

Comment: I am just making a randomly generated maths test as a 'first project' for learning C++ but the numbers are always the same when generated in the same second so I'd like a better way of making random numbers

Comment: @user9464295 You should `srand` only once, at the beginning of your program. But nowadays, there are better way of generating random number, such as the `random` standard library linked by @DanielJour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should stop using `srand` / `rand` since these are old ways of generating random numbers. Since C++11, there is a [`random`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) standard library:

```
#include <random>

std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, 100);

// To generate a number:
dis(gen);
```

Quick explanation:

- [`std::random_device`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device) is a random generator that can produce non-deterministic random numbers.
- [`std::mt19937`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine) is a specific instantiation of a [Mersenne Twister engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister) to generate pseudo-random numbers.
- [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) is a uniform number distribution. Here I generate number between 0 and 100 (included).

---

[`std::rand`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand) is also a [**pseudo-random** number generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator), but the random engine is implementation-defined, and you need to use `srand` to initialize it:

```
// Call srand once at the beginning of the program:
srand(time(0));

// Then you use rand() without (usually) calling srand() again:
rand();
rand();
```

But as you noticed, `std::time` usually returns a number of seconds, so if you run your program twice in a second, you will probably get the same output.

---

[`getrandom`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrandom.2.html) is a non-standard function (maybe POSIX?), there is really no needs to use it for a game now that the `random` standard library is available.